# how to disable android notification drawer

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have a react-native project running on android. It is a tracking app that applies the navigation foreground service. Therefor the app notification appears in the drawer.

[image: notification drawer]

When I press it to return to the app, all kinds of problems happen. Is there a way to disable what this onPress action does? So it just does nothing? like a return false?

Comment: "When I press it to return to the app, all kinds of problems happen" -- perhaps you should consider fixing those problems. After all, there may be other circumstances when the same problems will occur, such as when the user returns to your app from the overview screen, or when the user switches between windows in Android N's multi-window mode.

Comment: well I didn't think about the multi-window mode. but the issue is I am using a purchased navigation template and the seller has no advice on how to fix the problem. Having the foreground service enabled is not a must have option, but if there is a way to solve the workaround I am looking for then I would like to try it